# Is it possible to replace iterrows with something faster (e.g. apply) in my case?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bioinformatics

So I have a table that looks like the following:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rs10000911 | 4 | 144136193 | 100.000000 | - | AC |
| rs10000988 | 4 | 76010255 | 99.173554 | - | AG |
| rs10002181 | 4 | 142250415 | 100.000000 | + | AG |
| rs10005140 | 4 | 22365603 | 99.173554 | + | AG |
| rs10005242 | 4 | 5949558 | 100.000000 | + | AG |

Now I want to create an additional row or a series that would contain a combination of columns 1 and 2 that looks like this: 4:144136193, 4:76010255, 4:142250415, etc.
Now I am using an iterrows solution:

```
new_column = pd.Series([])
for index, line in table.iterrows():
    new_column = new_column.append(pd.Series(str(line[1])+':'+str(line[2])))
```

Because my table contains 800 000 rows iterrows is very slow. Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: Don't iterate over pandas DataFrame. See answers in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/55557758#55557758. If your task cannot be performed with pandas fanction, iterate over numpy arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

`df['new_column'] = df[1].astype(str) + ":" + df[2].astype(str)`

Answer (score 3):

```
df["new"] = df[["1", "2"]].apply(lambda x: ":".join(map(str, x)), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Or:

```
df["new"] = df[["1", "2"]].astype(str).apply(":".join, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            0  1          2           3  4   5          new
0  rs10000911  4  144136193  100.000000  -  AC  4:144136193
1  rs10000988  4   76010255   99.173554  -  AG   4:76010255
2  rs10002181  4  142250415  100.000000  +  AG  4:142250415
3  rs10005140  4   22365603   99.173554  +  AG   4:22365603
4  rs10005242  4    5949558  100.000000  +  AG    4:5949558
```

Comment: Hello. How did you insert such a table in your post?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
new_col = table.apply(lambda line: pd.Series(str(line[1])+':'+str(line[2])),axis=1)
```

This will give you a new dataframe `new_col`:

```
             0
0  4:144136193
1   4:76010255
2  4:142250415
3   4:22365603
4    4:5949558
```

(If want only a series, not a dataframe, `new_col[0]` will give you one.)